# Animate a RectangleGeometry (inside an Image.Clip) in Windows 8/Metro/Store

Tags: animation, windows-8, clipping

I am trying to animate an image Clip that is made using a `RectangleGeometry`.

However, I can't find any solution to do that. I have already reached the following conclusions:

- Windows metro doesn't support RectAnimation (straight forward solution for this issue)
- Windows metro [doesn't support PathGeometry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/451888a6-c26a-4d32-bf02-65119dcfca0a) in Cliping ([so I could do a workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/09/24/animating-clipping-paths-in-silverlight-2.aspx))
- Windows metro doesn't have `RectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` ([another solution presented by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752062.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding adding a Transform in the `RectangleGeometry` and I animated it:

```
<!-- In the Clip Section -->
<RectangleGeometry 
    x:Name="RectangleGeometry"  
    Rect="0,0,727,400" >
    <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
         <TranslateTransform x:Name="ClipTransform"/>
    </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
</RectangleGeometry>

<!-- Animate the Clip Section -->
<Storyboard x:Name="Anim">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        Duration="0:0:1" 
        To="-100"
        Storyboard.TargetName="ClipTransform"          
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"  />
</Storyboard>
```

I don't know if there is a better solution, but this one was the one I found.